# Creating and deleting instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

In file `index.html.erb`, I have code that prints some properties of each element of `@calender_items`:

```
<% @calender_items.each do |calender_item| %>​
  ...
  <td><%= calender_item.date %></td>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The instance variable is assigned by this line in a controller:

```
@calender_items = CalenderItem.all
```

If I comment out the this line, `index.html.erb` file still functions. Can someone give me any hints on why I can still access the instance variable even though it is no longer assigned? When do instance variables get destroyed?

Comment: You are showing very little of your code. So I suspect `@calendar_items` must be set somewhere, otherwise, your view code of `@calender_items.each` would complain about `each` not being a method of the `nil` class.

Comment: [ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/) is your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `before_filters` that could set the variable for some actions before firing them.
Check if the action you are calling are actually the action that you removed the instance variable. Ex.: `controller/index` calls `Controller` `def index` action.
Check the `ApplicationController`, maybe the variable is being set there too.

Instance variables only live through requests, so if you commented the code, it should not work.

Comment: Yes. Thanks that helped. Missed one line... :( My bad.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please be kind to accept it to further users with the same problem.